# why some module creation require us to include () and some don't in node js?

Tags: node.js, express, npm

if I want to create a module named 'a' for superheroes npm, I can just declare it without parenthesis

```
var a = superheroes; //no parenthesis


var randomSuperHero = a.random();
```

where if I want to create a module named app for express npm, I need  to include a set of parenthesis.

```
const express = require('express')
 

const app = express(); //parenthesis


app.get("/",function(req,res){

res.send("Hello World!")

})
```

why is this happening?

also, on this particular line of code,

```
app.get("/",function(req,res){
```

how does it know that the first parameter is the request and second parameter is response?
I am new to this and all this small things are confusing me like anything.

Comment: It depends on weather the module exports an object or a function. Node modules can export anything. If that "thing" is a string then that module is a string and you treat it like a string (strings cannot be called so you cannot add `()` to it). If that module is a number then it is a number. If that module is an object then it is an object.. you see where I'm going with this. If that module is a function then it's a function. And you call functions by adding `()` to it like `console.log()`.

Answer (score 1):

Some `npm` modules export at the top-level a function to be executed to construct an instance.

Take express-js,

[From the API documentation](https://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#express)

> express() - Creates an Express application. The express() function is a top-level function **exported by the express module.**

Let's take a look at the `superhero` module.
[The `index.js` file exports two properties](https://github.com/sindresorhus/superheroes/blob/main/index.js#L5-L6),

- random, a function
- all, a json blob

```js
const supe = require('superheroes');
const everyHero = supe.all //will give the contents of superhero.json
const randomOne = supe.random() // is an exported function
// calling supe() will throw an error as that is not an exported function
```